# URL does not work on prefixing www (in Chrome), otherwise working fine

Tags: google-chrome, url, www-mechanize

When I prefix 'www' to my site URL it does not redirect but just refreshes current page. But if I don't prefix www it opens the correct page. This is happening just for one URL and not for all.

Moreover on few computers this problem does not occur. There must be some browser specific settings.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your proxy settings are default.and If so try refreshing your browser by deleting your recent history.!